# How to make abbreviation of underscore or hyphen separated words using regex in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to make `abbreviation` of hyphen or underscore separated words, For instance:

## `hyphen-separated-words`

## `underscore_separated_words`

I use the code below for `hyphen-separated-words`, and it works fine.

```js
var hyphenSeparatedWords = "hyphen-separated-words";
var abbr = hyphenSeparatedWords.match(/\b([a-z])/g).join('');

console.log(abbr) // hsw
```

For `underscore_separated_words`, I use the code below. It works fine, but there are a lot of repetitions.

```js
var underscoreSeparatedWords = "underscore_separated_words";
var abbr = underscoreSeparatedWords.replace(/_/g, '-').match(/\b([a-z])/g).join('');

console.log(abbr) // usw
```

How to make an abbreviation of `underscore_separated_words` in the same way as the `hyphen-separated-words` without using `replace`?

How can I combine these two steps?

## Update

I have a d3 bar chart that we use internally. My font is large. And some of the xAxis labels are too long and overlaps other elements.I had two choices to fix the issue.

1. Wrap labels like this in [bl.ocks.org](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/7555321)
2. Make an abbreviation of them. When you hover on a bar or its label, display the complete name.

I opted to go for the second. Because the first one still occupies a lot of place.

Comment: Do you mean remove the hyphen / underscore?

Comment: In which way does what works for hyphens not work for underscores? Show sample input, output and desired output please.

Comment: well a _ is not a word boundry

Comment: `"underscore_separated_words".replace(/(?:_|\b)([a-z])[a-z]*/g, '$1')`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I don't see why you would need that `[a-z]*` at the end of the regex

Comment: Use `words.split(/-|_/).map(item=>item.charAt(0)).join('');` check the answer

Comment: @AnkitAgarwal I need to use regex

Comment: @mahan But it seems you want the one and only like yours? You know, the `.match(/(?<=_|\b)([a-z])/g).join('')` will only work in latest Chrome versions.

Comment: Would you elaborate on the allergy against `replace`?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thanks. It works fine.

Comment: @mahan It only works in latest Chrome versions. it does not work in FF, IE, etc.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I use latest version of  chrome (:

Comment: @mahan that uses regex inside `split` and using that was also short and understandable. Anyways glad to support you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not know why do not want to use replace but you can use a replace one liner, and use a replacer function:

```
"underscore_separated_words".replace(/[A-Z]+?(?:[_-]|\b)/gi,function(m,o,s){return m.slice(0,1)}); //usw
```

I think the above is way more concise and elegant

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you try with a regex in `split` that will split with either `-` or `_` and `join` them at the end after getting the first character.

```js
function abbr(words){
 return words.split(/-|_/).map(item=>item.charAt(0)).join('');
}


var words = 'hyphen-separated-words';
var res = abbr(words);
console.log(res);

words = 'underscore_separated_words';
res = abbr(words);
console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternate solution if you'd like to work on whole sentences:

```js
var str = 'Leave normal words and only abreviate underscore_separated_words.';

console.log(str.replace(/(?:_|(?=[a-z]*_))([a-z])[a-z]*/gi, '$1'));
```

[Here at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/0qlAzT/1/).